# Arduino with two (or more) push buttons

Tags: button

I am trying modify this setup for two push buttons https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button.

The code seems rather trivial

```cpp
int yellowButtonPin = 2;
int blueButtonPin = 4;

int yellowButtonState = 0;
int blueButtonState = 0;


void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(yellowButtonPin,INPUT);
  pinMode(blueButtonPin,INPUT);
}

void loop(){
  yellowButtonState = digitalRead(yellowButtonPin);
  blueButtonState = digitalRead(blueButtonPin);
  if (yellowButtonState == HIGH && blueButtonState == HIGH){
    Serial.write(3);
  }
  else if (yellowButtonState == HIGH && blueButtonState == LOW){
    Serial.write(2);
  }
   else if (yellowButtonState == LOW && blueButtonState == HIGH){
    Serial.write(1);
  }
  else {
    Serial.write(0);
  }
}
```

My problem is that there are several ground pins on the Arduino, but only one 5V pin, so I can't just simple double the circuits. Connecting the two circuits to different grounds but the same 5V didn't work out, although it seemed to be a good idea. How should I do this properly? To be honest, I actually would want to have three buttons, but I guess going from two to three will be trivial after going from one to two.

[image]

Comment: Chances are there is something wrong with how you built your circuit. Using the same 5V pin for both buttons is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Do I need different ground though? I'll edit with a circuit drawing in minute.

Comment: All the ground connections are identical and connected together. It makes no difference which ground pin your use.

Comment: There is only one ground. It may have multiple pins on it, but there is only one. Use whatever ground pin(s) you fancy, they are all the same.

Comment: @Majenko I edited the question with a circuit diagram, should that be ok?

Comment: I hope you don't expect characters '0' .. '3' in the Serial Monitor as you are sending characters: NUL, SOH, STX and ETX (ASCII values from 0 to 3) and they might not be visible.

Comment: I'm getting bytes \x00 through \x03 in python so that seems ok at the moment for my purposes.

Comment: Most people use a breadboard to easily spit the 5v into multiple wires.

Answer (score 2):

Learn about:

Built-in pullup resistors in Arduino
Debouncing

and checks this code: https://blog.adafruit.com/2009/10/20/example-code-for-multi-button-checker-with-debouncing/